# Compare lists then copy missing items to other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two lists. List 1 populated in Columns A and B, and List 2 populated in Columns D and E.

I want common items in List 1 and List 2 to be highlighted in yellow.

If an item is not present in List 1, but present in List 2, copy it to sheet 2.
If an item is present in List 1, but not present in List 2, copy it to sheet 3.

The code is not giving the intended output.

INPUT:
[image]

OUTPUTS:
[image]

Sheet2
[image]

Sheet3
[image]

```vb
Sub CompareTwoColumns()
    Dim compare1 As Variant, Compare2 As Variant
    Dim r As Integer, q As Integer, dif1 As Integer, dif2 As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim lr1 As Integer, lr2 As Integer
         
    lr1 = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Row
    lr2 = Range("d1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Row
             
    For r = 3 To lr1
        Set compare1 = Cells(r, 1)
        For q = 3 To lr2
            Set Compare2 = Cells(q, 4)
            If compare1 = Compare2 Then GoTo z:
        Next q
        
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 1).End(xlToRight)).Copy
        dif1 = dif1 + 1
        Sheets(2).Cells(dif1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
z:
        Cells(q, 4).Interior.Color = vbYellow 
    Next r
   
    For m = 3 To lr2
        Set Compare2 = Cells(m, 4)
        For n = 3 To lr1
            Set compare1 = Cells(n, 1)
            If Compare2 = compare1 Then GoTo y:
        Next n

        Range(Cells(n, 4), Cells(n, 4).End(xlToRight)).Copy
        dif3 = dif3 + 1
        Sheets(3).Cells(dif3, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
y:
        Cells(n, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: I am slightly confused. What is the role of Column B and Column E? Can you share a screenshot of how your data looks like? Also show us how the intended results should look like.

Comment: "But it's not giving the intended output" offeras awide range of problems - please some mor details about that too.

Comment: Added the intended inputs and outputs in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly ....

Before running the macro, the condition of the worksheets is something like this :
[image]

In Sheet DATA, there are two tables. First table range is in column A to B until whatever row, the second table range is in column D to E until whatever row. In the example of the image above, the last row with data of both tables ended in row 7.

The data in each column of both tables are not unique. As in the image in List1, there is "aaa" value which appear two times and in List2 there is "bbb" value which appear two times.

> I want common items in List 1 and List 2 to be highlighted in yellow.

if there is value in column A which found in column D (and vice versa), the cell of this value will have yellow background color. So in the sample image, the expected result in List1 cell A3:B3, A4:B4, A5:B5 ... will be yellow and in List2 cell D2:E2, D3:E3, D5:E5, D6:E6 will be yellow.

> If an item is present in List 1, but not present in List 2, I want
> them copy, pasted in sheet 3.

cell A1:B1, A6:B6 and A7:B7 will be copied to Sheet "NotInList2"

> If an item is not present in List 1, but present in List 2, I want
> them copy, pasted in sheet 2.

cell D4:E4 and D7:E7 will be copied to Sheet "NotInList1"

So, the result will be something like the image below :
[image]

If your case is similar with the example above ...

```
Sub test()
Dim rg1 As Range: Dim rg2 As Range
Dim rgData As Range: Dim rg2Check As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet: Dim i As Integer
Dim arr: Dim el: Dim rg as Range

With Sheets("DATA")
    .Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    Set rg1 = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rg2 = .Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For i = 1 To 2
    Select Case i
        Case 1: Set rgData = rg1: Set rg2Check = rg2: Set sh = Sheets("NotInList2")
        Case 2: Set rgData = rg2: Set rg2Check = rg1: Set sh = Sheets("NotInList1")
    End Select

    Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each cell In rgData: arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1: Next

    For Each el In arr
        With rgData
            .Replace el, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
            Set rg = Union(rg, rg.Offset(0, 1))
            .Replace True, el, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        End With
        If Not rg2Check.Find(el, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            rg.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            rg.Copy Destination:=sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next el
Next i

End Sub
```

Basically, the code loop two times to check List1 against List2 in the first loop, then check List2 againts List1 in the second loop.

In each of the outer loop, it create a unique value to check as arr variable.
Then it loop to each element in arr to get the cell address of the looped element, then it check if the looped element in arr is found in another List, then it put yellow color. If it doesn't, then it copy to the designated sheet.

Please note, the code compares what is in column A against what is in column D (and vice versa). It doesn't compare what is in column B against what is in column E (and vice versa).

---

```
Sub CompareTwoColumns()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh1 = Sheets("NotInList1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("NotInList2")

    lr1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    cek = False
    For r = 3 To lr1
      Set compare1 = Cells(r, 1)
          For q = 3 To lr2
            Set Compare2 = Cells(q, 4)
            If compare1 = Compare2 Then Compare2.Interior.Color = vbYellow: cek = True
          Next q
        If cek = False Then
            Range(compare1, compare1.End(xlToRight)).Copy
            sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    cek = False
    Next r
    
    cek = False
    For r = 3 To lr2
      Set compare1 = Cells(r, 4)
          For q = 3 To lr1
            Set Compare2 = Cells(q, 1)
            If compare1 = Compare2 Then Compare2.Interior.Color = vbYellow: cek = True
          Next q
        If cek = False Then
            Range(compare1, compare1.End(xlToRight)).Copy
            sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    cek = False
    Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping @Karma.. You understood my requirement perfectly. My bad that i didn't elaborate it in my question 

But got the error... 

Run-time error 1004. no cells were found at  Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)

Comment: Please don't directly implement it to your workbook, but try it first by making a new workbook then make the data and the name of each sheet exactly as in the sample image. Step run the code (hit the F8 on the keyboard), and when the yellow pass this `.Replace el, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False` , you should see both "aaa" in column A is replaced with the text TRUE. If that is what you see, continue press F8, and the yellow will pass `Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)`  without error, then you continue press F8.

Comment: The code works like charm. Thanks a lot for giving me this.  Let this quadruple your good karma. Earlier, I tried running the code with purely numbers and it didn't work. Now it works. Though I have zero understanding of scripting dictionary and replace methods you used, I will try to learn and understand your brilliant work.. 

You think my original code can't be repaired to meet my objective and get the output as u did with ur code?

Comment: @Gowtham, you can modify your code. I think the process is like this : 4 loops ---> 2 loops is the outer and inner to check list1 against list2, 2 loops is the outer and inner to check list2 against list1. The outer loop check other list within the inner loop, if same value - color it yellow, then flag it to TRUE. After the inner loop finish, it check if the flag is false then it copy the outer looped cell to the designated sheet. And so on. Please have a look in my edited answer.

Comment: This modified code works accurately and gives me what I wanted precisely. No words to thank you. I guess, application screenupdating property did the magic. Thank you so much again. I wish to upvote but I dont have enough credits to upvote you. However I pray God to keep you happy in all walks of your life, wherever u r, for helping selflessly..

Comment: In your first code with scripting dictionary, why do you add point before starting some lines of your code @karma? Eg: .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)). What's the use of it

Comment: I am sorry I can't explain it you. Anyway, that point is the same thing like when you write this code ,,,, `Sheets(2).Cells(dif1`. But if sheet(2) is needed again and again, then maybe better write like this : `with sheets(2)` ... Next line `set rg = .cells(dif1, 1)` ... Next line `.offset(1,0).value = "test"` next line... `end with`

Comment: Thank you Karma. That solved my doubt. Basically, instead of repeating something we are  using "With" and "." Thank you so much again

Comment: @Gowtham, yes you are correct :).

Comment: Thank you Karma. And what does the following piece of code do? Can you please tell

arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1:

Comment: Shame on me... again, I'm sorry I can't explain it to you in detail. Anyway, this kind of two lines are always go together : `Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")` ... `For Each cell In rgData: arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1: Next` ---> to populate the array (the arr variable) with unique item in rgData.